# Jenkins find installed plugins

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. I have installed some plugins like maven, JDK parameter on my local jenkins server. After installing the same it doesn't appear in the "Configure system" page. I tried to restart my machine, to see if its required but it didn't help. Could someone guide on what are the steps to be followed to use the installed plug in in the configure system page.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the official Jenkins wiki: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins

Make sure your Jenkins version supports the version of the plugins you want to install.

Comment: Thank you, Bernard. That was super helpful.